# Android App Bundle build Error: <fusing> element is missing the 'include' attribute

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, build.gradle, android-app-bundle

I am trying to develop an android app with dynamic features.

I have added "sample" dynamic feature module to project and when i tried to build "Android App Bundle" from Android Studio, i am getting below error,

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.manifest.ManifestFusingException$FusingMissingIncludeAttribute: <fusing> element is missing the 'include' attribute (split: 'sample').
```

Dynamic feature module manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
package="com.features.dynamic.sample">
<dist:module
    dist:instant="false"
    dist:onDemand="true"
    dist:title="@string/title_sample">
    <dist:fusing include="false" />
</dist:module>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

dist:include="false"

just add "dist:"

Comment: add total anser

Comment: Where to add this, in which module ?? can you explain more about this , i Am also getting this when i tried to build generate the signed APK.

Answer (score 2):

It should look alike this:

```
<dist:module
    dist:instant="false"
    dist:onDemand="true"
    dist:title="@string/title_sample">
    <dist:fusing dist:include="false"/>
</dist:module>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use latest version of [bundletool](https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases), I was using older version (0.3.3) jar file from [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/your-first-dynamic-app/index.html#4) 
sample demo. That was creating this issue.

Use follow the command to build

```
java -jar ~/Downloads/bundletool-all-0.10.0.jar build-apks --bundle=./app/build/outputs/bundle/debug/app.aab --output=out.apks
```

Note: bundletool-all-0.10.0.jar will be your latest jar file, You can get it from mentioned link.